# Repeated animation at random intervals?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I want to have an animation i created to repeatedly run at random intervals between each animation while the user is using the app.

I created a function where the animation is done.

```
         func Yawn () {

        Yawn1.append(character_atlas.textureNamed("1.png"))
        Yawn1.append(character_atlas.textureNamed("2.png"))
        Yawn2.append(character_atlas.textureNamed("3.png"))
        Yawn2.append(character_atlas.textureNamed("4.png"))
        Character_animate = SKSpriteNode(texture: Yawn1[0])
        Character_animate2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: Yawn2[0])
        Character_animate.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width/6.3, height: self.size.height/5.6)
        Character_animate2.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width/6.3, height: self.size.height/5.6)
        Character_animate2.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: self.frame.height*0.90)
        Character_animate.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: self.frame.height*0.90)
        Character_animate.zPosition = 3
        Character_animate2.zPosition = 3
        addChild(Character_animate)
        addChild(Character_animate2)
        var action1 = SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.animateWithTextures(Yawn1, timePerFrame: 0.4), count: 3)
        var action2 = SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.animateWithTextures(Yawn2, timePerFrame: 1), count: 4)
        var action3 = SKAction.sequence([action1,action2])

        var action4 = SKAction.runBlock({self.Character_animate.removeFromParent()})
        var action5 = SKAction.runBlock({self.Character_animate2.removeFromParent()})
        var action6 = SKAction.sequence([action4,action5])

        Character_animate2.runAction(action3,completion: {
            self.runAction(action6)
        })
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `NSTimer` and use a random number to define the `NSTimerInterval` between each fire of your function `Yawn`.

```
let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))  // This will return random number from 0 to 9 (10-1)
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(randomNumber, target: self, selector: #selector(YourVC.Yawn) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: where do I place that ? I wrote this NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(60.0, target: self, selector: Selector("Yawn"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

Comment: I place that in viewdidload and the animation began to overlap even with constant time.

Comment: What do you mean by overlapping ?

Comment: The time interval between the animations keeps decreasing. It looks like the animation is taking longer than usual.

Comment: Did you log the call to your function `Yawn()` so you can check that it's called every 60s ?

Comment: I am very new to coding. I dont understand what "Log the call to your function" means. Can you please explain?

Comment: In your function `Yawn` just add an 'NSLog("Yawn is called")` you will have in the console the time your function is called so you will be able to check if it's really called every 60s.

Comment: yes it does seem to be called every 60 seconds. The problem is i forgot to clear my yawn1 and yawn2 arrays. I got it to work now. Thanks so much!!